# Why separate PHP from HTML in a code as much as possible?

Tags: php, html, output

Twice now that I have asked and was responded that I should separate PHP from HTML in codes as much as possible. Instead of using:

```
<?php
echo "<p>The value of x is $valuex greater.</p>";
?>
```

That I should use:

```
<p>The value of x is <?php echo $valuex; ?> greater.</p>
```

Is there any difference I should know other than the format?

Comment: So that designers and programmers can work on the same project. Also it allows you to customize the "look" without risking to break the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the unique things about PHP is that it serves the purpose of both a server-side language *and* a templating language. Ideally, your code would be separated into controllers and views, where your controllers are *pure* PHP (without any HTML) and your views are *mostly* HTML (with minimal PHP). When you're writing a controller, PHP is just like any other server-side language. But when you're writing a view, PHP becomes a templating language, in which case HTML should rule.

Another good reason to separate the two is **syntax highlighting**. In your first example, most editors wouldn't realize that the text within the string is actually HTML, so they wouldn't know to apply syntax highlighting. This means your code will likely be harder to read than it could be, making life difficult for subsequent developers.

Answer (score 1):

You need `echo` in second one,

```
<p>The value of x is <?php echo $valuex; ?> greater.</p>
```

Or simply,

```
<p>The value of x is <?=$valuex ?> greater.</p>
```

**Read:** *[What's the best way to separate PHP Code and HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html)*. Also read [Escaping From HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Comment: of if you are useing php 5.2+ you can use the `<?= $valuex ?>` notation.

Comment: Sorry. I just forgot the echo... Any other differences? like loading speed is faster because less process or something?

Comment: I think you should more concern about `readability` & `formatting` rather than the speed.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is:

```
<?php $valuex = 6; ?>

<p>The value of x is <?php echo $valuex; ?> greater.</p>
```

Here you need to echo only php variable part.

```
<?php
echo "<p>The value of x is $valuex greater.</p>";
?>
```

Here you need to echo whole part.

Comment: So it's just the format? No 'the loading is faster if you separate' or something?

Comment: loading time for first one is nearly `0.0395700931549 sec` and second one is nearly `5.29289245605 E-5 sec`

Comment: @J.A.W.S.IbañezII You can vote up if it was really helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The output will be the same in both cases.

The first example is PHP outputting HTML code
The second example is HTML code with PHP inside it
The "Ideal" example is this:

```
<p>The value of x is <?=$valuex?> greater.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first one change the syntax like

```
<?php
   echo "<p>The value of x is ".$valuex." greater.</p>";
?>
```

and in the second one change to echo the value like

```
<p>The value of x is <?php echo $valuex; ?> greater.</p>
```

But both the notations are same,and work same

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that frankly you'll want to always be as flexible as possible. However, mixing your php with html means that your php-core is mixed up with your template, thus you'll have an a lot harder time maintaining, altering & providing different templates/languages etc. Thus always keep it apart.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to maintain your code, both HTML and PHP, when separating them.